# If stored procedure returns 1, throw error, else continue

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I have a stored procedure which is calling another stored procedure (cannot change this to a function). Depending on the result of the called stored procedure, I'd either like to throw an error, or carry on.

The stored procedure that is being called is looking for data in a table and returning 1 if it finds the data, or null if no data is returned.

How would the SQL look if I was using the following logic? If the stored procedure returns a value of 1, throw an error. If the stored procedure returns a NULL, carry on.

Comment: What you are trying put that in your question body also.

Comment: what do you mean "return"? Does the inner spc have a `select`?

Comment: Have a search for RAISERROR. You can invoke it IF your required conditions are met

Comment: A stored procedure can produce a result set containing a `NULL`, but it cannot return a `NULL`, as the return value is always a non-nullable `INT` (default `0`). If the output is indeed a table and you cannot rewrite the called procedure, you're looking at `INSERT .. EXEC`, CLR or `OPENQUERY`, none of which are very nice options. See [here](http://sommarskog.se/share_data.html) for details on how stored procedures can share data. By far the best option is to see if you can rewrite (or copy) the stored procedure to use an output parameter instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
    DECLARE @returnvalue INT
    EXEC @returnvalue = Stored_procedure_name

    IF @returnvalue = 1
    BEGIN
        --You could use THROW (available in SQL Server 2012+):
        --THROW <error_number>, <message>, <state>
        THROW 50000, 'Your custom error message', 1

    END
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Atahan, this doesn't appear to be setting the returnvalue to anything when run?

Comment: Hi Fler, stored_procedure you call with exec should return some value.